# On a rheem rtex-13 tankless water heater, i have 3 wires (red,black and white)and a ground entering the heater but only two hook up connectors

Tags: wiring

How do I make connections to wire the rheem rtex-13
My heater has 3 wires plus a ground wire coming in from the breakers. Two wires have 120v and one wire is common and one wire is ground. There are only two connectors in the heater. How do I connect the wires?

Comment: Pictures and/or wiring diagram will help.  A 240 volt heater usually only needs the black and red(or white) for power and ground for safety.  Neutral(white) only required on some devices that also need 120 volt only(clocks/lights, some controls).

Answer (score 3):

The white is isolated (capped off) and not connected, the red and black are connected to L1 & L2, and the ground connects to the metal case (not clear in the manual as the ground connection is ignored there - pictures from elsewhere show a green jumper screwed to the case, but it's unclear if that's user installed or factory installed.) Frankly shoddy not to have an actual ground terminal, and to ignore the ground wire (other than saying it needs to be there) in the instructions.

Likely reason for the un-needed /3 cable and white conductor is that the instructions do say to connect "red and black" to the breaker, so if you are following the instructions to the letter that would force you into /3 cable if not using conduit.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google shows it needs 6/2 wiring.

It is a high power consumer. 13 KW, 240 Volt, 54 Amps

The 2 (Red+Black) are 120 V each, and 240v combined.

It does not require the neutral (white) so cap it off.

The ground is to be connected inside to the metal housing.